# Why can't I define a variable at global scope after declaring it in an unnamed namespace?

Tags: c++, linkage

In my understanding:

- Names *declared* in an unnamed namespace are [added to the enclosing namespace scope and visible in that translation unit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces).
- With the `extern` specifier, a variable is not automatically *defined* (default-initialized).

I would expect the following to *declare* a variable and then *define* the same variable:

```
// Declare ::<unnamed>::my_obj with internal linkage and add my_obj to the
// enclosing namespace scope (the global namespace scope).
namespace { extern int my_obj; }

// Expected: Define the variable declared above.
// Actual: Declare and define a new object, ::my_obj.
int my_obj(42);
```

Instead, it declares two different objects, and warns me about the unused `extern int my_obj`.

**Why doesn't the second `my_obj` define the first `my_obj`? Isn't it in scope?**

Comment: Where did your first quote "Names declared in an unnamed namespace are added to the global namespace scope (for that translation unit)." come from?  It's not accurate.

Comment: Technically you're correct: the unnamed namespace definition "is treated as a definition of a namespace with unique name and a using-directive in the current scope that nominates this unnamed namespace." In *this* case, the current scope is the global namespace scope.

Comment: Interesting, VS2015, Clang and gcc [consider it is ambiguous](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a58e06fd6344315). But if you don't use the variable, then it compiles.

Comment: @flatmouse that site is blank in all of my browsers; what does it show? I don't get anything besides an unused variable warning in clang and gcc with `-Wall -pedantic`.

Comment: Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RJYs.png) of the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement *"names declared in an unnamed namespace are added to the enclosing namespace scope"* does not mean that members of unnamed namespace become full-fledged members of enclosing namespace. This addition is performed by an *implicit using-directive*. Such addition makes these names visible to name lookup, but does not make them literal members of the enclosing namespace for other purposes.

The problem you have in your code is the same as the one in the following snippet

```
namespace A
{
  void foo();
}

using namespace A;

void foo() // <- Defines `::foo`, not `A::foo`
{
}

// `A::foo` remains undefined
```

Despite the fact that we explicitly "added" names from `A` to the global namespace, it still does not mean that we can *define* `A::foo` as a member of global namespace using unqualified name `foo`.

In order to define `A::foo` in the above example you still have to refer to it using its qualified name `A::foo`. With unnamed namespaces this is impossible for obvious reasons.

P.S. Compilers typically implement unnamed namespaces as namespaces with internal compiler-generated names. If you somehow figured out a "hack" to discover that name, technically you'd probably be able to define your `my_obj` separately by using a qualified name in the definition. But keep in mind that the hidden namespace name is different in different translation units, thus producing a unique `my_obj` variable in each translation unit.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and improves my understanding, thanks! Also tested this by defining the same variable (without `extern`) in a later unnamed namespace in the same file (and in the same global namespace scope) and verified that it defined the previously declared `::<unnamed>::my_obj` object.

Comment: Even if you discover the name (most likely by getting a list of symbols from an object file), there's no guarantee you'd be able to actually use the namespace name yourself.  Case in point: compiling a file that only contains `namespace { int name; }` with MSVC, then obtaining the symbol list with `DUMPBIN /symbols`, you might find that the variable has a name like `?name@?A0xa7191b1a@@3HA`, where `?A0xa7191b1a` is the anonymous namespace's name.  Needless to say, this name can't legally be used in C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

An unnamed namespace is not a global namespace.  It is a specific namespace that is visible only within the translation unit in which it appears.

[This cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) describes this in more detail.

If you are trying to use a symbol defined in an unnnamed namespace within the same translation unit -- just use it!  It's in scope.  You don't need an `extern`

Comment: This question is about only one translation unit. From your reference: "Unnamed namespace definition. Its members have potential scope from their point of declaration **to the end of the translation unit**, and have internal linkage."

Comment: "internal linkage" != "global linkage"   `extern` says go look in some other translation unit for this variable which is pretty much the opposite of what an unnamed namespace does.

Comment: `extern` does not say "go look in some other translation unit". A variable declared `extern` may be defined in the same translation unit. In fact, because this is in an anonymous namespace, the object has **internal** linkage, so `extern` cannot possibly indicate the variable exists in some other translation unit here.

Answer (score 0):

from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tx32sw2.aspx :

A variable declared with the extern storage-class specifier is a reference to a variable with the same name defined at the external level in any of the source files of the program. The internal extern declaration is used to make the external-level variable definition visible within the block. **Unless otherwise declared at the external level, a variable declared with the extern keyword is visible only in the block in which it is declared.**

Comment: These are not [block-scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) declarations; they are namespace scope.

Answer (score -1):

Since the object is declared in a namespace, it must be defined in the same namespace (or rather, if a name is used as a declaration in one namespace and a definition outside that namespace, it refers to two different entities). That it is *visible* at file scope does not mean that it is a member of that namespace; I think the assertion that —

> Names declared in an unnamed namespace are added to the enclosing
>   namespace scope

— does not mean what you think it does.

The C++11 standard says that *An unnamed-namespace-definition behaves as if it were replaced by:*

```
[inline] namespace unique { /* empty body */ }
using namespace unique ;
namespace unique { namespace-body }
```

(paraphrasing slightly for formatting; the initial "inline" is optional, appearing iff it appears in the unnamed namespace definition).

So, would you expect in this:

```
namespace a_name {
    extern int a;
}
using namespace a_name;
int a = 4;
```

... that the first mention of `a` (inside the namespace) would declare the variable and the second define it? (If you would, at least this is consistent. But if you wouldn't, you need to recognize that the standard specifically says that you should get the same behavior from the unnamed namespace).

I don't believe there is any mechanism to declare a member in one namespace and provide the definition for the same member within another namespace, even if the member is visible in the second namespace.

To address comments below:

1. Yes, `extern` causes the declaration not to be a definition. I have removed the statement saying that `extern` had no effect, which was mainly in reference to linkage; that `extern` does not grant a name within the unnamed namespace external linkage is true, since C++11 (including amendments). Although in C++03 it may have technically granted external linkage, this was only as an attribute of the declaration/definition; the symbol was still not visible outside the translation unit and had no special visibility to the linker. The significance of `extern` on a member of the unnamed namespace in C++03 then apparently boils down to usability of that member as a constant expression, if it is a `const`-qualified pointer.
2. The [example that was linked](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/050213df940f9f8c) in a comment, following another comment stating that the linkage determined visibility of symbols to the linker which can have consequences, was perhaps intended to demonstrate that (in C++11) symbols in the unnamed namespace can have external linkage, and that non-external linkage pointers cannot be used as as template arguments (i.e. contexts requiring a constant expression) even when declared `const`. It did indeed fail to compile with GCC, however it compiles successfully with Clang and with the Intel compiler Icc. With any of the three compilers, the symbols declared in the inline namespace are local symbols at the link level (as can be seen using `objdump` for example) - there is no causal relationship between symbol visibility at the linker level and the error produced.
   C++11 explicitly makes a statement (3.5) to the effect that
   `extern`-qualified symbols shall have internal linkage if they
   reside in the unnamed namespace (specifically: *A name having
   namespace scope that has not been given internal linkage above has the same linkage as the enclosing namespace if it is the name of - a variable; or ...*). Furthermore, `const`-declared variables with internal linkage should be usable in contexts requiring a constant expression. By reading the standard, there can be little argument that the GCC compiler is behaving incorrectly in this case.

Comment: This is not true; `extern` has the effect of causing the expression to *not be a definition*. So the variable needs to be defined somewhere. ["In addition, a variable declaration that uses extern and has no initializer is not a definition."](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

Comment: @mgiuffrida you should check the actual standard text. I know that cppreference is based on it and is normally accurate, but it is not 100% the same.

Comment: you can try this yourself. Instead of int, use a class type with a constructor that prints something. When using `extern` the object is never constructed, because the variable is never defined.

Comment: From the standard: "A declaration is a definition unless... it contains the extern specifier or a linkage-specification and neither an initializer nor a function body."

Comment: **−1** “always has internal linkage”. On the contrary, the great advantage of anonymous namespaces in the C++03 days, was they provided external linkage for things that were effectively only visible within a given translation unit.

Comment: @davmac as it happens, the results are the same in C++03 and C++11 :-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf btw your demo compiles fine with Clang (LLVM compiler), no error whatsoever (with appropriate macro defined and all).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf In C++11 they do get internal linkage, though.

Comment: @T.C. If that holds for a variable declared as `extern`, then two of the three compilers need to be made aware of it.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf So it seems. (`extern` doesn't give something external linkage; it gives the linkage of the enclosing namespace.)

Comment: @T.C. What other explanation is there for the behavior? I checked and you're right about the formal, that it changed in C++11. The effect of that change, that we can measure it by, seems to be today that (1) compilers disagree about what's valid code, with apparently the majority (at least, g++ and Visual C++) disagreeing with the standard, and (2) that `extern` no longer has its intended mnemonic meaning.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The change was done by [CWG1113](http://wg21.link/cwg1113), but that issue is short on the motivations behind it. (Also, even in C++03, `extern` doesn't guarantee external linkage - `static void f(); void g() { extern void f(); /* OK, internal linkage */ }`.)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The intel icc compiler also successfully compiles your example. I would suggest that `extern` hasn't always had the intended mnemonic meaning (as you put it) for some time; a name declared in the unnamed namespace is not exported as a global symbol at the linker level even if it is declared `extern`, even in C++-03.